# Reusable component with Angular

Tags: angular

I want to create a widget which displays the list of schools in the state. It reads the list of schools from a json file and get refreshed every 5 minutes. This widget needs to be used outside the project as well. I mean I should be able to use this widget in other project with minimal effort. 
I am kinda new to angular. Can I create such a custom component with angular?

Template:

```
<main-component>
<app-school-list>  </app-school-list>
</main-component>
```

HomeController.cs-

```
public List<Schools> GetSchools(int stateId){
_homeService.GetSchools(stateId);
}
```

Comment: This question is going to be closed as you haven't provided any attempt. But go read this article on Angular libraries. https://nezhar.com/blog/up-and-running-library-development-with-angular-7/

Comment: Thanks. If I added an angular component library, will I be able to add the component as a normal child component inside the template and talk to the API to refresh the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a library then you can deploy it to NPM and consume it in different projects. Another solution is using polymer, you create your web component and deploy it to NPM and it can be used by different technologies like Angular, JS, React etc. web components are more generic than a angular library.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

https://blog.angulartraining.com/create-your-own-libraries-with-angular-cli-7b434600bbb7

Comment: If I go with the first approach i.e. angular library, will the component be able to talk to the API and refresh the list of schools periodically.

Comment: yes you can do that. Of course you will have to add logic and all that, but there are several npm packages that talk to an API

Answer (score 0):

To poll an api you use an RxJs interval

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SchoolService {
  schools$ = interval(300000).pipe(switchMap(_ => this.http.get('api/schools')));

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

and then in your component you can bind the schools to your template with the async pipe

```
schools$ = this.schoolService.schools$;

constructor(private schoolService: SchoolService) {}
```

and in your html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="school in schools$ | async">
  {{school.name}}
<ng-container>
```